# MySQL Greatest N Per Group Query Hangs

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table with columns PredCustId, StartDT and EndDT. For a given StartDT, there can be multiple PredCustIds. Here's what this looks like

[image]

For each unique StartDT, I would like to retrieve the row with the largest PredCustId. I am specifically trying to implement the left-join solution as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7745635/2146894) but the query hangs every time I run it and I don't understand why.

This works

```
SELECT a.*
  FROM PredCusts AS a
LEFT OUTER JOIN PredCusts AS b
  ON a.StartDT = b.StartDT;
```

but this hangs

```
SELECT a.*
  FROM PredCusts AS a
LEFT OUTER JOIN PredCusts AS b
  ON a.StartDT = b.StartDT AND a.PredCustsId < b.PredCustsId;
```

Why? Note that I am using MySQL 5.7.21 and MySQL Workbench 6.3.

EDIT
My table has ~370,000 rows. The only index is the Primary Key, PredCustsId.

Comment: Please edit your question and include information on the indexes which exist on this table. Also, how many rows do you have in this table?
 Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a inner join on a subquery for max value

```
select * from PredCusts p
inner join (
  select StartDT, max(PredCustId) max_precustid
  from PredCusts
  group by StartDT
) t on t.StartDT = p.StartDT and p.PredCustId = t.max_precustid
```

Comment: Thanks.  I found this solution as well.  My goal here is to understand why the proposed solution doesn't work (for my learning).  I'm also hoping the other solution is faster as this solution runs slow for me.

Comment: both the queries don't work because are simply left join .. in this way you just join the the rows based  on (all) startDT ..or the startDT < startDT .non evaluation about the max predCustID are involved  ..  in this way you never find the max value for each startDT  ... In SQL for this type of eavl there specificaaggregation function and operator sa group by .. hope this is usefull.

Comment: and for improve  performance check for proper index  on startDT

Comment: @Ben (nice handle btw) on a properly indexed table, no solution will be faster than this

Comment: This is the solution I'm rolling with for now.  Thanks a ton to both of you.