# Join two MySQL queries with where in condition and latest timestamp

Tags: php, mysql

First query is for select institutions and second is for get latest review to this institution.

First query:

```
SELECT 
    instituteId, 
    instituteName, 
    description 
FROM institutions 
WHERE instituteId IN ('1','2','3')";
```

Second query:

```
SELECT 
    name,
    review, 
    timestamp 
FROM reviews 
WHERE instituteId='1' 
ORDER BY timestamp DESC 
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: i don't see related column(s) in the select clauses or the wheres clause on how to join both queries..

Comment: through instituteId

Comment: Use CTR+K to format your query text.

Comment: ok @RaymondNijland

Comment: this kind of questions already occurred in SO,that's why given my answer in comment

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Greatest N Per Group Query Hangs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49222559/mysql-greatest-n-per-group-query-hangs)

Comment: ok @RaymondNijland

Comment: @kumar - what are the related columns in both tables? Does 'instituteId' exist in both tables? Please add the database schema for both tables (list all fields in both tables) so we can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT i.instituteId, 
       i.instituteName, 
       i.description ,
       r.name,
       r.review, 
       r.timestamp
FROM institutions i
INNER JOIN review r
ON i.instituteid = r.instituteId
INNER JOIN (SELECT instituteId,
                   MAX(timestamp) as timestamp
            FROM reviews
            GROUP BY instituteId 
            ) r1
ON r.instituteid = r1.instituteId 
AND r.timestamp = r1.timestamp
WHERE instituteId IN ('1','2','3')
```

Comment: SELECT i.instituteId, 
       i.instituteName, 
       i.description ,
       r.name,
       r.review, 
       r.timestamp
FROM institutions i
INNER JOIN review r
ON i.instituteId = r.instituteId
INNER JOIN (SELECT instituteId,
                   MAX(timestamp) as timestamp
            FROM reviews
            GROUP BY instituteId 
            ) r1
ON r.instituteId = r1.instituteId 
AND r.timestamp = r1.timestamp
WHERE instituteId IN ('1','2','3')

Comment: For large data set I think group by will take longer time than my answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do that. But the following one gives me the best performance in a large data set. And yes do not forget to indexing the columns.

```
SELECT i.instituteId, 
   i.instituteName, 
   i.description ,
   r.name,
   r.review, 
   r.timestamp
FROM institutions i
LEFT JOIN reviews r
ON i.instituteid = r.instituteId and r.timestamp=
(SELECT MAX(timestamp)
        FROM reviews where reviews.instituteId = r.instituteId 
        ) 
WHERE instituteId IN ('1','2','3')
```

Comment: "But the following one gives me the best performance in a large data set" Really?? A co-related subquery is most off the time the slowest executing one compared to JOIN's

Comment: In my case it gave me better than joining

Comment: if there is no review for id 3 then whats the output

Comment: I used left join as I want institute data even if there is no review.

Answer (score 0):

```
select i.instituteId, i.instituteName, i.description,
r.name,r.review, r.timestamp
from institutions i inner join reviews  r on i.instituteId=r.instituteId
WHERE instituteId IN ('1','2','3') 
ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can join two tables on a point that both the tables match the same value and property

Syntax:
SELECT column_name(s)FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.column_name=table2.column_name;

Solution:
SELECT i.instituteId, i.instituteName, i.description, v.name,v.review, v.timestamp 
FROM institutions i INNER JOIN reviews v on i.instituteId=v.instituteId
WHERE i.instituteId IN ('1','2','3') AND v.instituteId=1 ORDER BY v.timestamp DESC LIMIT 1;